# Cordova platform add android error

Tags: android, cordova

Using ubuntu 12.04

```
cordova platform add android
Creating android project...

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: An error occured during creation of android sub-project. 

/home/admin/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
    at /home/admin/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:87:29
    at _rejected (/home/admin/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:808:24)
    at /home/admin/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:834:30
    at Promise.when (/home/admin/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:1079:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/admin/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:752:41)
    at /home/admin/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
    at flush (/home/admin/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)

    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/platform.js:244:30
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:641:7)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:948:11)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:466:12)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i have the same error `An error occurred while listing Android targets` ever figure this out?

Comment: Exactly same error but... I can see both ~/adt/sdk/tools and ~/adt/sdk/platform-tools in my PATH running $ env. $ android opens android sdk manager as it should be so it means that is on PATH. ant is also on PATH. any idea?

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10 anything changed there?

Answer (score 12):

I was having what looks like the same problem. Make sure you add the ADT tools and platform-tools to your system path; doing this fixed the problem for me. Go to your .bashrc file (in your home directory) and add something like:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/your-path/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:/your-path/android-sdk-linux/tools
```

Then restart your session or do `$ source .bashrc` to enable the changes. Now cordova should be able to create the Android project just fine.

Answer (score 12):

Simple as download sdk, extract somewhere, export that path, do source to take effect, then continue... :)

**sudo gedit ~/.bashrc**

add "**PATH=$PATH:/opt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/sdk/platform-tools:/opt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/sdk/tools**" to the bottom.

make sure your path specified is correct., **adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321** changes according to the version you download.

**source ~/.bashrc**

to take path in to current session.

then from your build directory (mine is ~/phoneGapBuild/hello ).

**cordova platform add android**

(@) To see current path variables:

**echo $PATH**
(If you don't see newly added variables, please exit terminal and open it again)

(@) If you got an error like

> Error: ERROR : executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant
>   installed and added to your path.

run the following comment to install ant.
**sudo apt-get -u install ant**

Comment: or rename adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-{version number} to adt

Answer (score 2):

For windows edit the PATH variable from Control **Panel > System > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables**. Add the path to Android SDK's platform-tools and tools folder. For me it was **C:\Users\\MyPersonalStuffs\Software\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\platform-tools** and **C:\Users\\MyPersonalStuffs\Software\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\tools** location. Then make sure you open a new terminal tool for the PATH to take effect. Also make sure that you have **ant** available in the path as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today on my Windows7. My colleague send me an Ionic project and I couldn't run it on my device. Finally I removed platforms folder which was created by him and 
I add it myself  using:

**ionic platform add android**

and then it run normally after **ionic run android**

Hope it helps sb.

Answer (score 0):

**fix is here** (FOR WINDOWS ONLY)

I am facing the same problem of Build then i finally found out the solution.

**SOLUTION**
So You must have the Android Api 23 in order for this command to work.
Error of Daemon process will be solve after installing the Api 23 and extra 
build tools and run command 
COMMAND : cordova build android --release
I am sure this fix would help you to solve the problem.

**STEPS**
1. First check the version of android through this COMMAND:
   cordova platform help 
2. Run the build command after installing the Api 23 and extra build tools.
3. If Even this not work then Try add the variable in the 
 Environment variables > System variables > 
 add _JAVA_OPTIONS and value = -Xmx512M

Then Run cordova build android --release

BUT FIRSTLY SET UP THE ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES 
[Environment Variable setup Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5InU.png)

**COPY FROM HERE** 
ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES:-

1. **USER VARIABLES**
   **PATH** 
   C:\Ruby23\bin;C:\Users\kumar\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\ANDROID_SDK\tools;%SystemRo
   ot%\system32; %SystemRoot%; %SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;
2. **SYSTEM VARIABLES** 
   **ADD NAME AND VALUE** 
   2.1  **_JAVA_OPTIONS**   -Xmx512M 
   2.2  **ANDROID_HOME**    C:\ANDROID_SDK 
   2.3  **PATH** -> 
   C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin;C:\ProgramFiles\nodejs;C:\Gradle\gradle-4.0\bin;C:\ANDROID_SDK\tools;%SystemRoot%\system32; %SystemRoot%; %SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SystemRoot%\system32; %SystemRoot%; %SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;