# Cordova add platform error

Tags: android, cordova

When I try to type the command "cordova platform add android" I get this error:

**Creating android project...**

```
C:\Users\Andre\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;       
                          ^
Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
    at C:\Users\Andre\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\lib\check_reqs.js:87:29
    at _rejected (C:\Users\Andre\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:808:24)
    at C:\Users\Andre\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:834:30
    at Promise.when (C:\Users\Andre\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:1079:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\Andre\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:752:41)
    at C:\Users\Andre\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:574:44
    at flush (C:\Users\Andre\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Andre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\superspawn.js:112:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)**
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check this link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20897115/cordova-platform-add-android-error?rq=1

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20576704/phonegap-cordova-android-development?rq=1) one might also be helpfull.

Comment: let me know so I can assist you

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you install latest ant version 1.9.3.

http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi