# Error building Phonegap Application

Tags: android, cordova, ant, npm, android-build

I have created a phonegap project and added android platform via following http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface this document.
when i am trying to build it using this command:

cordova build
or
cordova build android

i am getting this error.

```
/usr/android/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:698: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt" (in directory "/home/keshav/Desktop/workspace/phonegap/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib"): error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:617)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute$Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Execute.java:862)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:481)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:495)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:631)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:672)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:498)
at com.android.ant.AaptExecTask.execute(AaptExecTask.java:699)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:120)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:398)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SubAnt.execute(SubAnt.java:302)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SubAnt.execute(SubAnt.java:221)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:120)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
... 68 more

Total time: 1 second

/home/keshav/Desktop/workspace/phonegap/hello/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
Error code 1 for command: ant with args: debug,-f,/home/keshav/Desktop/workspace    /phonegap/hello/platforms/android/build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
Error: /home/keshav/Desktop/workspace/phonegap/hello/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 8
at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

Comment: Did you install ANT and added the path of ANT bin in path variable?

Comment: @AtanuCSE yes, ant, android and java path are already set in path variable.

Comment: May be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26783594/814416 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/20897115/814416

Answer (score 0):

Download ant for windows, http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi. Extract and place it somewhere in your computuer. Mine is C:\ .

Open your CMD and type this command.

```
SET ANT_HOME=%PATH%;c:\apache-ant-1.9.4-bin
```

Restart your computer.

http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/11/02/common-errors-during-developing-android-app-in-mac-linux-and-windows-platform/